# Is there a polynomial ring R[x] which is not UFD when R is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Today I learned about factorization in polynomial rings.

In my book, it says that every unique factorization domain has a polynomial ring that is a UFD.

Also it gave me an example. $Z$ is a UFD but $Z[x]$ is not a PID. But it is a UFD since $Z$ is a UFD.

But I’m wondering if there is an integral domain R such that R[x] is not a UFD.

I tried to find an example, but I don’t know many integral domains. So it kept me from finding one. Could you give me an example?

Thanks.

Comment: If $R$ is not a UFD, then $R[x]$ is not a UFD.

Comment: For example, if $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, then $2\cdot 3=6=9-3=(3+\sqrt{3})(3-\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: How can I prove it? Contrapositive? If it is true, it suffices to find an integral domain that is not a UFD. I think there’s an example somewhere.

Comment: The degree zero polynomials in $R[x]$ are the elements of $R$.

Comment: Re: *it suffices to find an integral domain that is not a UFD*: [Domains that aren't UFD's](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=8&L=114)

Comment: Oh! I don’t know why many problems look hard for me at first but it was easy when someone gives me examples. Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: It is not surprising that many problems look hard for you if you just "learned it today" (see first sentence). After a few days with some examples it gets much better.